# How to convert str number from dec to hex

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Hello I have variable like this:

`uint8_t *str value = "100663296";`

I just wan't to convert to hexadecimal interpretation of str.
I doesn't need any math operations on this variable.

`uint8_t *output value = "6000000";`

How to do it correctly? I can't use convert to int and use sprintf because i don't have memmory for this on my MCU.

Comment: How would you do manually? Continuously divide by 16 in decimal representation, yielding one digit after another. You might be trying something alike, reusing the decimal string's character's that have already been evaluated. This should work as target base is larger than source base. Don't forget to revert the resulting string afterwards.

Comment: If code for `printf` itself is too large: Compilers for many microcontroller offer ways to exclude floating point conversions, which are most complex ones. Maybe you should check for.

Comment: Do you know the math involved in converting a decimal number into hexadecimal? If you don't, you'll need to learn that math first. If you do, then just implement the math, verbatim, in C++.

Comment: Do you have enough memory for `itoa()`? You're going to need at least enough for a cut-down version of it, whether you include someone else's code or write your own.

Comment: @TimRandall Considering comments to [first answer given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67619490/1312382), I assume problem is rather `printf` function – because of accidentally enabling floating point conversions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: missed the part about MCU and memory limitations :) this answer won't be useful

You can try to do the following:

- convert your string representation of the number to integer value (you can use `int atoi( const char * str );` function
- once you have your integer you can print it as HEX using, for example, `sprintf` function with `%x` as a format parameter and you integer as a value parameter

Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/axAPWH

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int n;
    char hex_val[50];
 
    n = atoi("100663296");
    sprintf(hex_val, "%x", n);
 
    cout << hex_val;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what question author excluded because of 'not hav[ing] memory for' – whatever she/he meant by this (maybe too large for int/long/long long?).

Comment: sprintf is default this is disabled on STM32 compiler, when I add -u _printf_float flag to compiler, program using 60% memory

Comment: @user22090909 If I recall correctly, that's not fully correct. `printf` should be available, but by default without support for floating point numbers (`%f%e%g` and alike). You need that compiler flag to enable the floating point conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `<charconv>` if available:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  auto const* str = "2147483647";
  errno = 0;
  char* end;
  long i = std::strtol(str, &end, 10);

  if (end == str || errno == ERANGE)
    return 1;

  char out[20];
  auto const [p, err] = std::to_chars(out, out + sizeof out, i, 16);

  if (err != std::errc{})
    return 2;

  *p = 0; // null terminate

  std::puts(out);
}
```